# How to preload css :hover background-images

Tags: css, preload

I have multiple background-images that change on hover.

Example:

```
.class1 {
    background: url(/img/img-1.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}
.class1:hover {
    background: url(/img/img-2.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}
```

The images flicker now, as they are loaded the second you hover over them.
I've tried using sprites, but that doesn't work, as the images change size for mobile devices.

Any ideas? Could be css or jquery, doesn't matter much

Comment: You could add `<link rel=preload as=image href="img/img-2.jpg">` in the head - but this is not fully supported yet

Comment: Tried it, no effect, at least for safari and firefox. Are you sure it works for background-images? Or maybe it just didn't work because, like you said, it isn't fully supported. Thanks tho

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=preload - both safari (11-) and firefox don't support rel="preload" - if you try this in chrome you should see this work

Answer (score 6):

You can use HTML5 link prefetch like this in the `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/img/img-1.jpg" />
```

Info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ

Comment: I've just tried it, doesn't seem to work for me. I didn't put it in the head tho. I have 2 images per page and I don't want to put all images in the header.php, so I've put it for 2 images in the index.php (and so on). Can't see a difference

Comment: It depends on how big your images are. If they are really heavy, you need to use some slow connection to see the difference of when you load the page with prefetch and without. It is also necessary to disable cache (or clear it before every try). If your connection is good and images are not very heavy, you will not notice the difference.

Comment: And it works for any kind of images (background or not). The idea is that the browser has the image in its cache and renders it faster, whenever it is needed: for background or as an image tag.

Comment: Thanks to you I just realized that the images I use are really huge. I've made them smaller before, but they got replaced so I have to do it again. Thanks! Might that be the reason it didn't work? I will try it again.

Does it work for all browsers?

Comment: I've even put it in the <head> now but my images are still flickering. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Tried it with Safari and Firefox

Comment: How big (in pixels) are the containers? How many KB are your images? What is the extension of the images?

Comment: The containers change size when you change the size of your browser. the images are all >100kb (40-80kb). They are all .jpg

Comment: I think there must be another reason, why your images are flickering. They are not heavy at all, especially if there are only two images per page. So the proposed solution doesn't influence anything. I suggest to you to make a codepen (https://codepen.io/ -> Create -> New Pen) with your code so that we can find the reason.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the case...
I don't want to share the code, so I guess it's no help. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I know it may be a late answer, but here's the most simple solution that I found: just add invisible ::before pseudoelement with the desired background-image, i.e:

```
element::before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: url(image_name);
  content: '';
}
```

so it will preload the image. If you use SASS it's even easier, as you can create a simple mixin for this.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following technique:

```
.class1:hover,
.class1-hover-preload {
    background: url(/img/img-2.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}
```

and added the elements with `-hover-preload` classes to my html into a container with 0 height. This way, I keep the path definition for preloaders in the same place as the elements (CSS itself) so that if they are changed for hover, preloading won't get broken.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making two  containers (instead of only one before) for the pictures, hide one of them(the hover one), and made them blend in for :hover. It works now.
I still don't know why none of the other solutions worked which is sad, but well, at least it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found that works (tested in Firefox and Chrome on Mac), is to paint the image with opacity: 0, like this:

```
&::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: url(image.png);
}
```

Bit it's still not 100% reliable. In Safari it flickers quite much still.

Answer (score -2):

You could try forcing the browser to download the div by including it in the html of the page, but styled so that it doesn't appear.

For example:

**CSS**

```
.hidden-images {
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="hidden-images">
    <img src="/img/img-2.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

You may have to do some more work to prevent the images being shown or affecting the browser window visibly but hopefully the basic idea is clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've already tried that tho, nothing changes. Found that kind of answer for other questions on here, but I think it doesn't work for css background-images.